# CentOS 7 Virtualbox VM SSH Connection Suddenly Refused

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I am new to linux and am working with a minimal CentOS 7 installation on a VM running on Virtualbox with a Win10 host.

Up until today, I was able to use PuTTy and WinSCP to SSH into the VM from the host without any trouble. Today, after NO changes to the VM at all, it says connection refused on SSH. HTTP still works, the nginx webserver is still accessible from the host.

The port forwarding and firewalld config of the VM were not touched. It is a local VM and I am the only one with access.

`firewall-cmd --list-services` includes ssh

`nmap -sT -O localhost` lists 22/tcp as open

I have the port forwarding on the VM set to host port 2222 going to port 22 on the guest. 2222 is what I could previously connect to SSH through from the host.

Everything looks correct to me and I did not change anything so I am entirely stumped. Any help is appreciated.

The only thing I did differently today than before was I chose to Save Machine State on shutdown rather than just Power Off like I had every other time I turned it off.

Comment: Have you updated your computer recently?

Comment: @GabrielFair - No, it did the April update last week but that was before this VM was created. I do not recall it updating since then.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of an answer since I do not understand the reason why this fixed it, but changing the port forwarding on the machine to 22222 instead of 2222, which I had been using before, fixed it.

I can now PuTTy and use WinSCP to connect once again, but now to 22222

If anyone has any insight as to why this happened please comment. Otherwise, if you cannot connect and everything looks correct otherwise try changing the host port mapping to something new.